# Is it possible to use Katalon Chrome's Extension offline?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, automated-tests, katalon-recorder

I'm currently using the Katalon extension for Chrome which allows me to record actions on the browser and then play them, without my interaction or at least the minimum. I realized that when you start recording your actions, the extension will notify you. I installed the extension on my personal laptop and when I tried to use it I realized that it does not record any operation and does not notify them of anything obvious. The problem in question is that on the laptop I try to do these operations offline, something that was fixed when I connected it but because I'm not always online I would need some way (if possible) to use this tool without being connected to the INTERNET.

The browser version is Google Chrome 60.0 and Katalon Recorder (Selenium IDE for Chrome) 2.1.0

Thanks.

Comment: On behalf of Katalon team, we would like to sorry for this inconvenience. We definitely will have the ability for the extension to work fully without the internet in near future and will keep you updated once it is included.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for using Katalon Recorder.

Since 2.2.0 offline mode is supported.

If you have any other questions, don't hesitate to let us know. We are more than happy to help you.

Comment: I downloaded the version 2.2 about 30 minutes ago and still have the same problem: I can not work offline since when running the tests try to connect to this url https://www.katalon.com/ as a first step, when this fails it does not execute them